# Rails 7.0.4 API: Images uploaded with Active Storage not showing after server update

Tags: image, rails-activestorage, ubuntu-server, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm working on a Rails 7.0.4 API-only application where users can upload images using Active Storage. The images are stored locally on the server. However, I'm facing an issue where after updating the server with a new release, the images uploaded in previous releases are not visible. Instead, only the image links are displayed, and I'm seeing a 404 error when trying to access the images directly.

Here are some additional details:

I have confirmed that the image files exist in the storage directory on the server.
The image URLs are generated correctly using the rails_blob_url helper in my serializer.
The images were accessible before the server update, so I suspect it's related to the deployment process or file paths.
I have tried moving the image storage location outside the application directory, but the issue persists after updating the server.
I need assistance in resolving this issue so that the previously uploaded images remain accessible even after updating the server with new releases. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this problem.

Please let me know if you need any further information or code snippets to help diagnose the issue. Thank you!

Comment: 404 is file not found, so can you check what the url is that is causing the 404 error please and post it up in your question and then check the link directly in your browser

Comment: i think problem is with configuration of files which i am not able to understand.i have created a new directory on server which is outside of release path is /home/deploy/uploads i want that my all images should store in this path .in my config.yml i have changed the path with this path do i need to make changings in any other file i am using Capistrano to deploy

Comment: That's dangerous, potential security risk, there is absolutely no need to store anything outside of the asset pipeline or the public folder or sub folders there in. If you really want them stored outside of your applications directory structure then use a CDN such as Amazon Web Services, there are hundreds of examples of how to do this. Otherwise perhaps you could set up a symlink to the shared folder and let capistrano handle that but your app will know nothing at all about anything in your servers folder structure outside of it's root folder unless you use an asset host.

Comment: Remember that files have to be publicly accessible to the outside world

Comment: how i can symlink .i show yoy my code example can you please guide me further

Comment: this is my deploy.rb                                                                                                                      set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('public/storage')
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads','storage'

Comment: this is storage.yml                                                                                                                       local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("shared/storage") %>

Comment: You need to add these details to your question please

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is our images are stored in rails app storage folder.when we update server with new release it removes all that images because now we have new folder.          Solution is create a new directory outside of your current folder in my case i named it shared.                                                                            First go to your project on local machine and open Config/storage.yml file and write this

```
  local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Now go to deploy.rb file and add this line

```
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'storage', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads', 'node_modules'
```